# Import-SPWeb invalid date/time data

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have exported a SharePoint 2010 document library using SharePoint Central Administration to create a backup cmp file. This was all good. The library contains a date/time field called EnrolmentDate. There are 6000 rows in total and about 2000 of these rows have an EnrolmentDate value of 1/1/1900.

When I try and use Import-SPWeb to import into another site, only 4000 rows are imported. The rows containing the enrollment date 1/1/1900 do not import and are generating an error in the import log file which states:

> Error: Invalid date/time value. A date/time field contains invalid data

I was under the impression that the range for the date/time data in SharePoint type starts at 1/1/1900. These values are in the original list so not sure why they won't import?

I have checked the sites regional settings and they are the same. It seems no one else in the history of SharePoint has encountered this error as I can't find it online anywhere.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: After testing different scenarios I believe that the Import-SPWeb does not even attempt to import the rows with an Enrolment_Date = 1/1/1900.  It validates them before it imports them and deems the date invalid.  I changed 1 of these rows Enrolment_Date to 2/1/1900.  I used Export-SPWeb to create the cmp files and then imported the backup using Import-SPWeb and this row came through.  So I am thinking that maybe internally the date 1/1/1900 may be being stored as a date prior to this sometime in 31/12/1989 and therefore invalid.  I am in NZ 12 hours ahead of UTC time.  any thoughts appreciated

Comment: In the end we manually changed all of the 1/1/1900 dates to 2/1/1900 by copy and paste in data sheet view of the document library.  Then the Export and Import was successful.